# Why is spring boot returning empty for currently logged in user?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring boot version 2.5.6, and trying to get the currently logged in user so i can use it to get other details about the user in order to create their profile.

I used the following code to find the user but it returns empty in the log. All internet search shows that this is the proper way to get the currently logged in user.

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)){
    currentUserName = authentication.getName();
    user = userRepository.findByTag(currentUserName);
    log.info("User is logged in "+ user);
}
```

Comment: may I ask what are you using as client-side?

Comment: you need to set AuthenticationPrincipal during security filter process , if you haven't done anything specifically unless its internally handled in someway.

Comment: @providerZ the client-side is react native, but I'm working on the backend apis so I use swagger to test them

Comment: The anser to this question is because there is no authenticated user. Why there is none is a different question because you havnt showed us anything about HOW you authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add requestContextFilter.
if you are using web.xml try:

```
  <filter>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>RequestContextFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>RequestContextFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RequestContextFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

another option in using @AuthenticationPrincipal or Authetication

Comment: I'm using pom.xml

Comment: if you are using it inside a rest call / API you can put as one of the parameters.
example:
@GetMapping("/")
 public String index(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal) {}